# Log in with my domain

Tags: php, api, authentication

I'm very familiar with a lot of sites that use log in with Google, Facebook, etc. I was curious if someone could point me into the right direction of how I could make a system for other sites to log in using my site or if there is a tutorial covering what goes into a system like this that someone could link me to. I know it won't get as popular as Google and Facebook, but it'd help me since I have multiple domain names. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel when not required, read up on [OpenID](http://openid.net/). I suppose it will help with your problem!

Comment: Someone has sent me to OpenID before, but I just want a system for my sites alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, so it depends on your choice. For example, you can create an api, which will create a cookie and hold it in a db, and also send it to the client which requested to login, in another server. And after that, all session check requests will be handled through the main (api) server - you will handle it in that way, it will not be handled automatically ;).

Comment: Thanks. This has me pointed now in the right direction as to how I can achieve it.